# How do I apply a function to an certain object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a method that works on a method, like this, inside the 're' python module:

```
_compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
```

the function finder is being applied on _compile, How? does the return type of _compile is string, and if it's so how can it possible to create methods that applies on strings?

Comment: No it isn't. The `_compile` function returns an object of some kind (presumably an instance of `re.Pattern`). `finditer` is a method of that object.

Comment: No, the return type of `_compile` is **not** a `str`, presumable if this is from the `re` module, then this is simple `re.compile` and it returns a `re.Pattern` object, which makes sense, since that has a `finditer` method

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can if you create a class that has the instance method `finditer` and return it in the `_compile` method. This is essentially what re does.

Without knowing what you’re trying to do exactly I’ll show you what I mean:

```
class CompiledClass:

    def __init__(self, pattern, flags):
        #setup class here

    def finditer(self, s):
        #perform the find or whatever it is you’re doing on the string and yield each result or return a list.

def _compile(pattern, flags):
    #do any checks or setup before creating/returning the class
    return CompiledClass(pattern, flags)
```